# Plot multiple DataFrame columns in Seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

I am using the following code

```
import seaborn as sns

g = sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, col='A', hue='A')
g.map(plt.plot, 'X', 'Y1')
plt.show()
```

to make a seaborn facet plot like this:
[image: Example facet plot]

Now I would like to add another row to this plot with a different variable, call it Y2, on the y axis. The result should look similar to vertically stacking the two plots obtained by

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, col='A', hue='A')
g.map(plt.plot, 'X', 'Y1')
plt.show()

g = sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, col='A', hue='A')
g.map(plt.plot, 'X', 'Y2')
plt.show()
```

[image: Example plot with two rows]

but in a single plot, without the duplicate x axis and titles ("A=<value>") and without creating a new `FacetGrid` object.

Note that

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(dataframe, col='A', hue='A')
g.map(plt.plot, 'X', 'Y1')
g.map(plt.plot, 'X', 'Y2')
plt.show()
```

does not achive this, because it results in both the curve for Y1 and Y2 being displayed in the same subplot for each value of A.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I used the following code to create a synthetic dataset which appears to match yours:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Generate synthetic data
omega = np.linspace(0, 50)

A0s = [1., 18., 40., 100.]

dfs = []
for A0 in A0s:
    V_w_dr = np.sin(A0*omega)
    V_w_tr = np.cos(A0*omega)
    dfs.append(pd.DataFrame({'omega': omega,
                             'V_w_dr': V_w_dr,
                             'V_w_tr': V_w_tr,
                             'A0': A0}))
df = pd.concat(dfs, axis=0)
```

Then you can do what you want. Thanks to @mwaskom in the comments for `sharey='row'`, and `margin_titles=True`:

```py
dfm = df.melt(id_vars=['A0', 'omega'], value_vars=['V_w_dr', 'V_w_tr'])
g = sns.FacetGrid(dfm, col='A0', hue='A0', row='variable', sharey='row', margin_titles=True)
g.map(plt.plot, 'omega', 'value')
```

This results in

[image]

### Update

- As of this update, the correct method is to use [`seaborn.relplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.relplot.html#seaborn.relplot), which plots a FacetGrid.

```py
sns.relplot(data=dfm, x='omega', y='value', col='A0', hue='A0', row='variable', kind='line')
```

[image]