# How to plot multiple dependent variables with seaborn?

Tags: python, pandas, accelerometer, seaborn

I want to consider time-series data, the three axes of an accelerometer to be exact.  I'm digging through the docs but am not immediately seeing how provide more than one signal and trying to figure out how to organize my data for pandas and seaborn in general.  After plotting a single run of the three signals, I hope to overlay multiple runs of those same signals to get a plot like this but for three signals:

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

data = [['t', 'x', 'y', 'z'],
        ['0', '1.024', '0.9980', '1.001'],
        ['1', '1.0-4', '0.9080', '1.021'],
        ...]
sns.set(color_codes=True)
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['t', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
sns.tsplot(time='t', y=['x', 'y', 'z'], data=df).savefig("testing.png")


ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

[pandas DataFrame docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html)
[tsplot docs](https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/generated/seaborn.tsplot.html)

Is there no way to combine these separate plots?

[Plot multiple DataFrame columns in Seaborn FacetGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30623721/plot-multiple-dataframe-columns-in-seaborn-facetgrid)

Answer (score 3):

This seems to work:

```
N=100

num_runs = 3
out = []
for k in range(num_runs):
    data = np.random.rand(N,3) + np.sin(np.arange(N)/5)[:,np.newaxis]
    data = np.hstack([np.arange(N)[:,np.newaxis],data])
    data = np.hstack([np.zeros(N)[:,np.newaxis]+k,data])
    out.append(data)

data = np.vstack(out)

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['sub','t', 'x', 'y', 'z'])
dfm = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['t','sub'], value_vars=['x', 'y', 'z'])
dfm
sns.tsplot(time='t', 
           value='value', 
           condition='variable', 
           data=dfm,
           err_style="boot_traces", 
           unit='sub',
           n_boot=50)
```

[image: plot]

The data frame looks like this after `pd.melt`

```
    t   sub variable    value
0   0   0   x   0.952150
1   1   0   x   0.343075
2   2   0   x   0.630453
3   3   0   x   0.998851
4   4   0   x   1.237932
5   5   0   x   0.958720
```

Couple comments:

- tsplot wants the traces de-pivoted with a label column.  `pd.melt` does this for you.
- tsplot is also expecting multiple "trials" for a given variable, hence the loop I used to make the example dataframe.  Even if you only have one trace, you need to have a `unit` column that you can pass to tsplot.  Without that, I couldn't get it to work.